# Pasar variable de nodejs (Express) a Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongoose

Suponga que tengo una base de datos en mongodb, en la cual logro almacenar cierta información con .save() pero ahora bien, quiero recuperar esa informacion y pasarla al cliente, por la que uso findOne() para adquirir el dato deseado, ese dato quiero pasarlo al cliente mediante una variable. He buscado en Google pero me salen soluciones usando engines y la verdad es que yo uso HTML puro ¿Alguien que me de la luz verde? ¿Cómo paso variables de Express a Javascript de cliente para luego mostrarlas en la vista?

Comment: Hay un motor de renderizado para express que te entrega HTML. Desconozco cómo se configura. Te comento que para mí lo más sencillo es trabajar con RESTFul. Envías una petición (get, post, etc) y reformas un JSON. Despues con tu frontera interpretas estos datos. Así mantienes la lógica separada de la vista y la BD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen dos formas de poder enviar datos desde el servidor para que este sea mostrado en el cliente:

1. Usando tu servidor de node como API REST que retorne un formato de intercambio como `JSON`
2. Pasar lo que obtienes de mongo y enviarlo a un motor de plantillas [template engines](https://expressjs.com/es/advanced/developing-template-engines.html)

La que elijas dependerá mucho de la forma en la que estes realizando tu aplicación, la primera opción la usan para los SPA (Single Page Application), la segunda seria para una web tradicional (como lo harías con Laravel, Rails o Django) donde le pasas la información a la plantilla, esta obtiene los datos y la traduce en el html.

Comment: esto tiene pinta de comentario extendido, por favor lee [answer]